# Assigning values printed by PHP CLI to shell variables

Tags: linux, bash, shell, php

I want the PHP equivalent of the solution given in [assigning value to shell variable using a function return value from Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2115615/assigning-value-to-shell-variable-using-a-function-return-value-from-python)

In my php file, I read some constant values like this:-

```
$neededConstants = array("BASE_PATH","db_host","db_name","db_user","db_pass");
foreach($neededConstants as $each)
{
     print constant($each);
}
```

And in my shell script I have this code so far:-

```
function getConfigVals()
{

 php $PWD'/developer.php'

    //How to collect the constant values here??
 #echo "done  -  "$PWD'/admin_back/developer/developer.php'
}

cd ..
PROJECT_ROOT=$PWD
cd developer

# func1 parameters: a b
getConfigVals
```

I am able to execute the file through shell correctly.

To read further on what I am trying to do please check [Cleanest way to read config settings from PHP file and upload entire project code using shell script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4374345/cleanest-way-to-read-config-settings-from-php-file-and-upload-entire-project-code)

**Updates**

Corrected `configs=getConfigVals` replaced with `getConfigVals`

**Solution**

As answered by Fritschy, it works with this modification:-

PHP code -

```
function getConfigVals()
{
    php $PWD'/developer.php'
    #return $collected
    #echo "done  -  "$PWD'/admin_back/developer/developer.php'
}
```

shell code -

```
result=$(getConfigVals)
echo $result
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to execute the function and assign what is printed to that variable:

```
configs=$(getConfigVals)
```

See the manpage of that shell on expansion for more ;)

Comment: Thanks that works. But I still have to explode the result. Is there any single step to initiate many variables in my shell script? I want to initiate exactly those constants (variables in shell script) (as many constants in my php file -> those many variables with same values in my shell script)