# Initiating dynamic variables (variable variables) in bash shell script

Tags: linux, bash, shell, variables

I am using PHP CLI through bash shell. Please check [Manipulating an array (printed by php-cli) in shell script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4377191/manipulating-an-array-printed-by-php-cli-in-shell-script) for details.

In the following shell code I am able to echo the `key`- `value` pairs that I get from the PHP script.

```
IFS=":"

# parse php script output by read command
php $PWD'/test.php' | while read -r key val; do
    echo $key":"$val
done
```

Following is the output for this -

```
BASE_PATH:/path/to/project/root
db_host:localhost
db_name:database
db_user:root
db_pass:root
```

Now I just want to initiate dynamic variables inside the while loop so that I can use them like  `$BASE_PATH` having value `'/path/to/project/root'`, `$db_host` having `'localhost'`

I come from a PHP background. I would like something like `$$key = $val` of PHP

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may try using the `eval` construct in **BASH**:

```
key="BASE_PATH"
value="/path/to/project/root"
# Assign $value to variable named "BASE_PATH"
eval ${key}="${value}"

# Now you have the variable named BASE_PATH you want
# This will get you output "/path/to/project/root"
echo $BASE_PATH
```

Then, just use it in your loop.

---

EDIT: this read loop *creates a sub-shell* which will not allow you to use them outside of the loop. You may restructure the read loop so that the sub-shell is not created:

```
# get the PHP output to a variable
php_output=`php test.php`

# parse the variable in a loop without creating a sub-shell
IFS=":"
while read -r key val; do
    eval ${key}="${val}"
done <<< "$php_output"

echo $BASE_PATH
```

Comment: @Martin thanks, this works but there is variable scope issue outside the while loop. I am able to echo the variable right after the eval line inside my loop, but not outside the `done` keyword of the `while` loop

Comment: You are right, that's because the read construct creates a sub-shell. Then the inner variables will not be visible outside of the loop. I will update the answer with alternative solution...

Comment: Sorry it does not work like this. If I separate the `while` from the `php` command (like you have done instead of `php $PWD'/test.php' | while read -r key val; do`), the while loop executes only once and `$key` and `$val` are empty.

Comment: also please tell me what does the `done <<< "$php_output"` statement do? I have no variable called `$php_output`. Is it a keyword? If I keep the `while` loop and the `php` command together (like in my question) and just add this `<<< "$php_output"` or  `<<< "$BASE_PATH"`, the variables do not echo inside as well as outside the loop.

Comment: `php_output` is just a variable I declared in my second example (first command). `<<< "$php_output"` redirects the content of variable `$php_output` to the while loop
What happens if you run the code I suggested, does it work? It works for me...

Answer (score 4):

Using `eval` introduces security risks that must be considered. It's safer to use `declare`:

```
# parse php script output by read command
while IFS=: read -r key val; do
    echo $key":"$val
    declare $key=$val
done < <(php $PWD'/test.php')
```

If you are using Bash 4, you can use associative arrays:

```
declare -A some_array
# parse php script output by read command
while IFS=: read -r key val; do
    echo $key":"$val
    some_array[$key]=$val
done < <(php $PWD'/test.php')
```

Using process substition `<()` and redirecting it into the `done` of the `while` loop prevents the creation of a subshell. Setting IFS for only the `read` command eliminates the need to save and restore its value.

Comment: thanks for the tips but using either of your solutions, my script dies out without running anything (due to the `done < <(php $PWD'/test.php')` part). I tried putting an `echo "before"` before the while condition and `echo "after" read simply` after the loop. But nothing is echoed and the script does not prompt for any user input.

Comment: @Sandeepan Nath: My examples work vary similarly to Martin's second example. If that one works for you then mine should as well. It doesn't make any sense that your test `echo` statements don't do anything. I don't understand why the redirected process substitution would cause your script to die out.

Comment: Thanks for alerting us about the security risks related to using `eval`. You didn't actually touch on the security risks, so I did a little research. Here's a link to a site that illustrates the good and bad uses of `eval` in detail. [Eval Command And Security Issues](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/048)